# Consumers going down for Oracle advanced queue

Tags: oracle, queue

When the consumers go down due to some fatal error, no xml is dequed related to that consumer.
But if we ignore the fatal error and consumer does not go down then all the messages related to that consumer will be dequed.

But the message on which the fatal error came will not get dequed and it will be acting as a loss of data or information.

How can the loss of data be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a WHEN OTHERS THEN wrapper exception handler at the highest level of your consumer, and if you catch a fatal error then write enough information to an 'error' queue that gets monitored by someone (support team, administrator and so on) that is sufficient to identify the message that caused the fatal so it can be 're-processed' or handled somehow.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..Most of the exceptions are handled. Some how fatal error comes may be due to webservice down.A lot of information is there.It is ok if we want to do manually.But how can we reprocess that message on which fatal error has come through coding only.How to handle it?Do we create a temp table to store the fatal messages or something?

Comment: Once you've pushed enough information onto an error queue (a temp table is just a basic error queue) to identify the message again you can add a counter and have a retry consumer try to reprocess it another x times every n minutes until it either goes through or fails again - at which point someone will have to investigate it.

Comment: what are the alternatives to Oracle AQ?